# Merging two noteboooks into one in Jupyter (ipython)

Tags: jupyter

I have two different Jupyter notebooks for two different projects. I would like to merge them to get them both on the same notebook.

One way is to copy cells from one to the other one but it seems to be quite a bit of work for projects containing many cells. Is there a feature supporting importing Notebook documents or copying multiple cells at a time?

Answer (score 30):

You can merge notebooks with [nbmerge](https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge)

Install it with pip

```
pip install nbmerge
```

and merge your files with

```
nbmerge file_1.ipynb file_2.ipynb file_3.ipynb > merged.ipynb
```

Comment: Does not work in my case, where the notebook had a lot of plots and outputs.

Comment: Does this have to be executed on a fresh Jupyter Notebook or the Anaconda command prompt - sorry if it is a stupid question, beginner here.

Answer (score 15):

`pip install nbmerge`

`nbmerge file_1.ipynb file_2.ipynb file_3.ipynb > merged.ipynb`

full documentation - https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge

Comment: It doesn't work yet with unicode characters inside the jupyter notebook, the issue persist in its github page.

Comment: Works with unicode for me. Replace `> merged.ipynb` with `-o merged.ipynb`

Answer (score 11):

You can indeed copy multiple cells at a time - use Shift + J or Shift + Down to select the next cell in a downwards direction, and in an upwards direction with Shift + K or Shift + Up.  You could then copy and paste them en masse to another notebook, and preserve the cell divisions by making sure the destination notebook is in Command mode (cells have blue border).

See http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Notebook%20Basics.html# and https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

install nbmerge:

```
pip install nbmerge
```

run the following:

```
!nbmerge file_1.ipynb file_2.ipynb file_3.ipynb > merged.ipynb
```

Answer for those who missed to exclaim

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the notebooks  you want to merge are in the same folder/directory and put these code in  new jupyter cell (pls don't forget the exclamation mark)

```
 !nbmerge file_1.ipynb file_2.ipynb file_3.ipynb > merged_ouput.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this sort of thing a few times in the past using a text editor on the .ipynb file. It's a json format that's fairly easy to follow. My use case was to move a series of cells into another notebook, more or less as an archive activity.

Make sure you have a backup strategy in place in case you break the json format by leaving out a comma or some such!

You end up with an invalid checksum, which you are warned about when you first open the changed notebook(s). After saving them the first time, a new checksum is created and the warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting parts of a notebook into another one is a use case for [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext). Jupytext can export (the inputs) of your notebooks as `.py` or `.md` files. Execute either

```py
jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py --sync *.ipynb
```

or

```py
jupytext --set-formats ipynb,md --sync *.ipynb
```

Then edit the text files, move the desired inputs from one file to the other, and update the corresponding `.ipynb` files with

```py
jupytext --sync *.ipynb
```

Please note that only the outputs for which the inputs were unchanged are preserved in this operation.

Jupytext is also available as a plugin for Jupyter. In that context, you don't need to use the command line. You can *pair* your notebook to the desired text file using the File/Jupytext menu (Jupyter Notebook) or the Jupytext commands (Jupyter Lab). And you just have to refresh your paired notebook in the browser to get the latest edits on the paired text file.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new Jupyter Notebook in the same directory as the previous notebooks you wish to merge.

In the new Jupyter Notebook, run this: `pip install nbmerge`  .

Then, restart your Kernel.

Finally, run this:

`!nbmerge your_first_file.ipynb your_second_file.ipynb your_third_file.ipynb -o merged.ipynb`

Check your directory for the newly created merged file (`merged.ipynb`)

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to create a new Notebook in the same directory as the notebooks you wish to merge.

then type the following:

1. pip install nbmerge
2. import nbmerge
3. !nbmerge name1.ipynb name2.ipynb name3.ipynb -o new_name.ipynb

This should work

Answer (score 0):

### Bottom Line Up Front:

- pip install nbmerge
- pip install nbformat
- nbmerge file1.ipynb file 2.ipynb > merged.ipynb

Just figured out why it was erroring out for some individuals in this section.
I'm running Virtual Studio with Python 3 using Jupyter Notebooks. It seems like nbmerge calls out to a class called nbformat that didn't exist on my computer. Using pip installed fixed my problem. I did all of this within the same directory as my python files.

Reference:
https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge/blob/master/nbmerge/__init__.py

Comment: That fix might help someone since it worked.`nbformat` is included within the `requirements.txt` for nbmerge (it is [the only thing in it](https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge/blob/master/requirements.txt) & so it is definitely weird why it wouldn't get installed during the first `pip` step? (Aside: if you installed modern Jupyter then nbformat should be around as it normally comes as part of modern Jupyter. I suspect it would have worked without needing the extra pip for nbformat if you ran it inside a Jupyter Notebook you had running Visual Studio Code by using ...

Comment: <continued>  the exclamation point in front of `nbmerge` that some others here suggest. You could install `nbmerge` inside Jupyter via `%pip install nbmerge` and the restart the kernel.)